# VSTS Web App using Typescript: Could not copy the file "xxx" because it was not found

Tags: typescript, azure-devops

I've started using Typescript with AngularJS in my ASP.NET 4.5.2 Web App. It all works well with VS2017 both building and publishing.

However I can't get it to build with Visual Studio Team Services. Its giving me the error:

> Error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "xxx" because it was not found.

where file xxx is the resultant `.js` file compiled from the typescript files as per the configuration in `tsconfig.json`.

How can I get this to work?

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "none",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "outFile": "client/ts/client.js",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "files": [
    "clientts/proposal/premium/list.ts"
  ]
}
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jghivcmdaij8iqt/vsts_log.txt?dl=0

`tsconfig.json` is included in the project as a content file.

The log file shows the following, which implies that it is reading `tsconfig`, because otherwise it wouldn't be trying to copy those files.

```
2017-12-05T05:33:21.7241345Z GetTypeScriptCopyToOutputDirectoryItems:
2017-12-05T05:33:21.7241865Z Adding items with BuildAction=TypeScriptCompile to the same collections that will be populated (with items of other BuildActions) by the GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems target
```

Comment: Did you try this? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f43ceb9e-f253-46e3-a496-05f8cd77f634/msb3030-could-not-copy-the-file-because-it-was-not-found-error?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: Its a generated file, so doesn't get added to the project. That fact that its failing to copy the file proves that the build engine is expecting it to be there - but for some reason its not.

Comment: Set system.debug variable to true, then queue new build and post the detail log here, also provide the detail code of tsconfig.json.

Comment: Log file and tsconfig added.

Comment: Based on the log file, it doesn't use tsconfig.json. Where do you put tsconfig.json? Is it in your project? Do you include client/ts/client.js to your project? What's the structure of your solution? Can you share a simple sample on the OneDrive that can reproduce this issue?

Comment: tsconfig is at the root level of the project and is included in the project. client/ts/client.js isn't included in the project - I saw a task there in the log file which automatically adds that to the list of files to be copied *because* its listed in tsconfig.json I thought? Man, it would take me forever to build a cutdown version of the project and then it would most likely work.

Comment: I've edited the question and added the relevant lines from the log file which indicate that its knows to copy the output from the Typescript compilation across - and that can only be found from tsconfig.json can't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the solution is creating new build definition.